# XSL - Modify XML Export to Excel to resize columns

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I'm using an XSL file to modify an XML file to generate an Excel spreadsheet - this is working well but I would like to increase the width of the columns. I can't use the:

```
<xsl:attribute name="ss:AutoFitWidth">1</xsl:attribute>
```

option as all my columns are being generated as text as they could contain a mix of text, numbers and dates, and the docs for the [XML Spreadsheet Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx) mentions that the use of this means that the 'column should be autosized for numeric and date values only. We do not autofit textual values.' so that's not an option.

Does anyone know a way to have the columns resized or specify a value for the width of the column so I can at least increase the width to more closely reflect the content in each column?

Here's my current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="06-06-2017" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 16.0.2"/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnA" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnB" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnC" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnD" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnE" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="FlagBold" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="6">
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="900">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Created: 15-August-2017</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="901">
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="902">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Name</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>ID</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Number</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Amount</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="904">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Acme Corp Pty Ltd</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>123456</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category 1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$456.78</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="905">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Demo Company Pty Ltd</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>987654</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category 2</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$789.32</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

and here's my XSL that creates the spreadsheet rows:

```
<Style ss:ID="MyTitleStyle">
    <Alignment ss:WrapText="0" />
    <Font  ss:Bold="1"/>
</Style>

<xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
    <Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL">
            <Cell>
                <xsl:if test="../fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA = 1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">MyTitleStyle</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>           
                <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </Data>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:for-each><!-- next column -->
    </Row>
</xsl:for-each><!-- next row -->
```

Comment: You can specify an `ss:Width` attribute on the `Column` element under `Table`, but you would obviously need to know what width you wanted to set it to. Are you looking to just set a fixed width, or try and set the width based on the length of text that may occur in the column?

Comment: @TimC Ideally I'd like to set this on the widest value in the column, but if not possible could live with setting a fixed width